# React Display Route Container without header and footer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

This is a react component - Inside of the render method, when the path is '/' render HomeContainer and when it's '/dashboard' render the DefaultContainer. Issues I'm having is with exact paths. When I'm on the dashboard I don't want to see the navigation or footer. Adding exact path inside the HomeContainer isn't rendering the DefaultContainer when the path is '/dashboard'. Having issues implementing this. Any thoughts?

```
HomeContainer = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" render={props => <LogIn {...props} />}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />;
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  };

  DefaultContainer = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app_container">
        <SideNav />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/recent" component={Recent} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/AddNote" component={AddNote} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/ToDo" component={ToDo} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={this.HomeContainer} />
            <AuthRoute path="/dashboard" authed={this.props.auth} component={this.DefaultContainer} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it if you will add exact into `<Route path="/" component={this.HomeContainer} />`, also please read the documentation about Switch, it finds first route that matches regexp and render it, therefore you need either look on it order or add exact for every inner route. And keep in mind that switch only works for direct child, not for child of child

Comment: Getting to realise what switch does the more I go on, fixed by placing the <authRoute /> first